# Unexpected result when generating a gray8 bitmap using C# on Win7

Tags: c#, bitmap, windows-7

The following code generate a gray8 bitmap image file. It works fine on Win10.

```
var width = 4;
var height = 4;
var rect = new Int32Rect() {
  Width = width,
  Height = height,
};

var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Gray8, null);
var data = new byte[width * height];
for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    data[i] = (byte)(i * 2);
}

bitmap.WritePixels(rect, data, width, 0);
var encoder = new BmpEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
using (var s = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
{
    encoder.Save(s);
}
```

But when I execute it on Win7, the pixel value is unexpected.

Expected:

```
 0  2  4  6
 8 10 12 14
16 18 20 22
24 26 28 30
```

Actual:

```
 0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0
17 17 17 17
17 17 17 17
```

I had tested with other value, the generated pixel value is always `input / 16 * 17`.

The encoder final calls to [WindowsCodecs.dll](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/Imaging/BitmapEncoder.cs,825), but I cannot find much info about it.

Any idea about this issue?

Comment: I can't spot any obvious errors in the example code. I would check the color space of the produced bitmap to see that it did not do any color conversions. I would also try using System.Drawing.Bitmap and see if that works better.

Comment: If you want platform-independent handling of images that isn't affected by variations in Windows GDI+ from one OS to another, consider using the LEADTOOLS Imaging SDK. (Disclosure: I work for its vendor.) If you'd like to try the SDK, there's a free evaluation [here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads) that comes with documentations, sample code and free technical support.